# $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{1-x}}dx<0.5$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Prove:
       $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{1-x}}dx<0.5$

My solution:
$( x+1>x)$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{1-x}}dx< \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{1-x}}=0.5
$$

Is there a closed formula  for the integrals

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the denominator by it's conjugate?

Comment: If you consider hypergeometric functions are closed form, then the first integral is $-\frac{1}{4} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};-1\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\pi }{18 \sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Ah, with your edit, you know how to prove this question. Are you asking for the closed form just to see if it exists? If so, the title shouldn't be "integral < 0.5".

Comment: Yes, I am only looking for that may beta fuSnctSion?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $$\sqrt[3]{(1+x)}^2
-\sqrt[3]{1+x}\sqrt[3]{1-x}+\sqrt[3]{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Pleae show the solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Use that $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Comment: That is ok. Find the integrals

Comment: The indefinite integral is given by $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x} \left(-3 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{x+1}
   F_1\left(\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};\frac{x+1}{2},x+1\right)+2
   \sqrt[3]{-x} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};x\right)+(x+1)^{2/3} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};x+1\right)+3 \sqrt[3]{-x} (x+1)^{2/3} x+3
   (1-x)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-x} x-3 \sqrt[3]{1-x} \sqrt[3]{-x (x+1)} x+2 \sqrt[3]{-x}
   (x+1)^{2/3}-2 (1-x)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-x}\right)}{12 \sqrt[3]{-x}}$$

Comment: The definite integral is given by $$\frac{1}{216} \left(-9 i 2^{2/3} \sqrt{3} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};2\right)+9\ 2^{2/3} \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};2\right)+10\right)+\frac{27 i
   \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3};2\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}+2 \left(5
   \sqrt{3}-3 i\right) \pi \right)$$

Comment: It is $$\approx 0.40436597521118120154829061283029824712183820762278$$

Comment: We have by AM-GM $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}+\sqrt[3]{1-x}}\le \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{2\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}\le \frac{1}{2}$$ since $$0\le 1-x^2-x$$ for $$0<x<0.6$$

Answer (score 1):

A less scary closed form is:
$$\frac5{12}\rho^2-\frac{\pi}{36\sqrt 3}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{18}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho^2+1}{3}\right)-\frac1{36}\ln\left(1+\frac{3\rho}{(\rho-1)^2}\right)$$ where $\rho=2^{1/3}$.

I will add the proof soon.

---

Proof:

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $(1+x)^{2/3}-(1-x^2)^{1/2}+(1-x)^{2/3}$,

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\int^1_0 x^{1/3}\left[(1+x)^{2/3}-(1-x^2)^{1/3}+(1-x)^{2/3}\right]dx \\
2I&=\underbrace{\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1+x)^{2/3} dx}_{A}-\underbrace{\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1-x^2)^{1/3} dx}_{B}+\underbrace{\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1-x)^{2/3} dx}_{C} \\
2I&=A-B+C
\end{align}
$$

---

Let $\rho=2^{1/3}$.
$$\begin{align}
A&=\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1+x)^{2/3} dx \\
&=\int^{1/2}_0\frac{w^{1/3}}{(1-w)^3}dw \qquad x=\frac{w}{1-w}\\
&=3\int^\rho_0\frac{y^3}{(1-y^3)^3}dy
\end{align}
$$

Integral calculator says
$$A=\frac56\rho^2+\frac{\pi}{18\sqrt 3}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{9}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho^2+1}{3}\right)-\frac1{18}\ln\left(1+\frac{3\rho}{(\rho-1)^2}\right)$$

---

$$\begin{align}
B&=\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1-x^2)^{1/3} dx \\
&=\frac12\int^1_0 y^{-1/3}(1-y)^{1/3}dy \qquad y=x^2 \\
&=\frac12\mathcal B\left(\frac23,\frac43\right) \\
&=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(\frac23)\Gamma(\frac43)}{\Gamma(2)} \\
&=\frac12\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)\Gamma\left(\frac13\right) \\
&=\frac16\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{\pi}3)} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3} 
\end{align}
$$

---

Similarly,

$$\begin{align}
C&=\int^1_0 x^{1/3}(1-x)^{2/3} dx \\
&=\frac12\mathcal B\left(\frac43,\frac53\right) \\
&=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(\frac43)\Gamma(\frac53)}{\Gamma(3)} \\
&=\frac12\frac13\frac23\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)\Gamma\left(\frac13\right) \\
&=\frac19\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{\pi}3)} \\
&=\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3} 
\end{align}
$$

Hence, 
$$I=\frac5{12}\rho^2-\frac{\pi}{36\sqrt 3}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{18}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho^2+1}{3}\right)-\frac1{36}\ln\left(1+\frac{3\rho}{(\rho-1)^2}\right)$$
which is approximately $0.43027$.